# echo an array data from json decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to echo an array data from json decode result, so I have tried both the file_get_contents and also curl which works.

This is the response I get from the server which is json output..

```
{"Servers": {
 "lastChangedDate": null,
 "ServersList":  [
    {
   "online": "The server is UP",
   "offline": "The server is DOWN",
   "maintainace": "The server is currently in maintenance mode",
   "location": "EU",
   "ip": "x.x.x.x"
  },
    {
   "online": "The server is UP",
   "offline": "The server is DOWN",
   "maintainace": "The server is currently in maintenance mode",
   "location": "US",
   "ip": "x.x.x.x"
  }
 ]
}}
```

now then the output will be an array like this after decoding it..

```
Array (
    [Servers] => Array (
        [lastChangedDate] =>
        [ServersList] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [online] => The server is UP
                [offline] => The server is down
                [maintenance] => The server is currently in maintenance mode
                [location] => EU
                [ip] => x.x.x.x
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [online] => The server is UP
                [offline] => The server is DOWN
                [maintenance] => The server is currently in maintenance mode
                [location] => US
                [ip] => x.x.x.x
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Here is my php code

```
<?php 
    $request = file_get_contents("test.json");
    $input = json_decode($request, true);
    echo $input['Servers']['lastChangedDate']['ServersList'][0]['online'];
?>
```

demo with print_r ($input); instead of echo http://phpad.org/run/1666334020

So in my main page I want to output to be like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEEPMG.html

Comment: `$input['Servers']['ServersList'][0]['online'];` should work

Comment: that works man.. thank you.. you could've posted as answer so I could mark it as an answer.

Comment: print_r output is indented if you display it properly. just follow the indentation down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entries `$input['Servers'];` and `$input['lastChangedDate'];` are on the same level in the array, so you can't access`$input['Servers']['lastChangedDate']`.

I think you're trying to do:

```
$input['Servers']['ServersList'][0]['online'];
```

Answer (score 1):

in the json you posted above 'lastChangedDate' is null means you can't access it with

```
$input['Servers']['lastChangedDate']['ServersList'][0]['online'];
```

First you should find why lastChangedDate is null.
$input['Servers']['lastChangedDate']**['ServersList'][0]['online'];**

The bold text is where the access conflict begins. PHP should also output you an error like "Undefined index: ServerList" so you need to first fill lastChangedDate to make further requests to its content

Could it be you wanted to access

```
$input['Servers']['ServersList'][x]['online'];
```

Comment: he shouldn't traverse this way and has nothing to do with NULL, because the structure is like this: Servers->ServersList-> etc.

Comment: he is calling lastChangedDate in his example which is NULL, so i assume it was just a mistake he called lastChangedDate

Comment: I think it was null for the last years or so, I don't really know why though.. since I don't have a contact with those developers.. im new to php so I didn't really knew whether to call it or not.